# Better way to exclude category output for post/pages?

Tags: exclude, categories

I always assumed there was a way to exclude certain categories from being output in the loop using `get_the_category`, `the_category`, or one of the `term` related functions. After looking around it seems like the only way is to grab the array and just remove them by ID or name.

For instance this is what I am using:

```
<?php // exclude category ID 12 as an example.

      foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
        if (!($cat->cat_ID =='12'))
         echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/category/' 
         . $cat->category_nicename . '/">'. ' | ' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
      } 
?>
```

This looks kinda messy due to having a somewhat "hard-coded url" using `/category/` ( I know I can also change this but it still seems counter intuitive).
Is there no better way to exclude categories?

Comment: You can run a filter on [`list_terms_exclusions`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1289) to exclude terms site wide, or simply one side or the other(admin or front)...

Comment: Ok I tried this but could not get it to work, here are some examples I tried, http://pastebin.com/j4KKPFKY, any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL being "hard-coded" is the problem you can use [**`get_category_link`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
    if ($cat->cat_ID !='12')
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'"> | ' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bainternet, this does work but after thinking about it I want to remove it from all side wide output (front-end) instead of changing all the templates, I have updated my question.